# Bridge in ipv6 mode

Tags: linux, networking

I created a bridge on Ubuntu and assigned an IPv6 address to it:

```
# ifconfig br1
br1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1a:65:a0:13:71:84
      inet6 addr: 2001:220:abcd:70::40/64 Scope:Global
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:e7:d1:c6:24:05
      inet6 addr: 2001:220:abcd:70::25/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::7ae7:d1ff:fec6:2405/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:383758 errors:0 dropped:164 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:116401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:191849350 (191.8 MB)  TX bytes:8911276 (8.9 MB)
      Interrupt:17

# route -6 -n
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
2001:220:abcd:70::/64          ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
2001:220:abcd:70::/64          ::                         U    256 0     0 br1
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 br0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 tap0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 tap1
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 br1
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  3383 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1   395 lo
2001:220:abcd:70::25/128       ::                         Un   0   1  2412 lo
fe80::100c:e5ff:fe0b:8414/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::68f7:bbff:fe7f:21a5/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::7ae7:d1ff:fec6:2405/128  ::                         Un   0   1   657 lo
fe80::b40f:3aff:fe58:b0ce/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 br0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 tap0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 tap1
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 br1
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1  3383 lo
```

I'm unable to ping br1 on the host. However, I'm able to ping another Ubuntu system whose IP is 2001:220:abcd:70::26. **Also, br1 does not show up in the output of 'ifconfig'; I'd have to do 'ifconfig br1' to list it.**

Any thoughts on this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess you have to disable the 2001 IP on the eth0 interface, since the forwarding interfaces shouldn't have an IP.

Comment: I need the IP assigned to eth0 for other systems to communicate with it.

Comment: @Maddy Can you assign it to the bridge instead?

Comment: Maybe you can use the link-local address for management, but I'm not sure if this IP is reachable while in forwarding state.

Comment: This might work with the systems in the same subnet. This machine needs to be reachable from other networks too.

Comment: Then assign the IP to the bridge and prevent unwanted connections with a firewall-rule. You cannot assign IPs to an interface which is part of a bridge.